# Java: Generating a BigInteger random prime using Rabin Miller test

Tags: java, rsa, primes

Im trying to generate a random Big Integer and check if its prime using the Rabin-Miller test. I cannot use certainty or generate a new big integer prime.I keep getting numbers that are not prime.

Heres my code

```
public static BigInteger generateRandomPrime(int numBits, Random rand, boolean print) {

  BigInteger result = new BigInteger(numBits, rand);
    BigInteger result2 = new BigInteger(numBits/2, rand);
  int counter=0;

    int res=0;
    if(result.mod(TWO).equals(ZERO))
        result = result.add(ONE);

    while(print==false)
    {
     while(counter<=30 || res!=0)
     {
           res=RabinMillerTest(result, result2, print);
        counter++;
     }
        if(res!=PROBABLY_PRIME)
     {
            result.add(TWO);
        }
     else
        print=true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: My RabinMillerTest method is working 100% so the problem is with this code

Comment: Can you supply at least the javadoc for your RabinMillerTest? I don't know how to interpret `res!=0` etc.

Comment: RabinMiller returns 0 for probably prime. 1 for composite with factor and 2 for composite with no factor

Comment: @pnizi Please specify at least the behavior of your `RabinMillerTest` method, it is unclear what `result` and `result2` do, and it appears to me that `print` is completely irrelevant to the Rabin-Miller Test

Comment: Without a specification for `RabinMillerTest` it is difficult to see the point of doing it 31 times with the same inputs. Isn't it just going to go on returning the same result?

Comment: The standard version of Rabin-Miller Test is a probabilistic algorithm, so it may return different output every time. The `while` loop is actually an implementation of the Monte Carlo method for increasing the success probability of the algorithm. But nonetheless, the specification for `RabinMillerTest` is crucial for us to have a clear picture of what's going on

Comment: @chiwangc Thanks, that explains that loop. However, that means `counter` needs to be set back to zero inside the `while(print==false)` loop - on the second and subsequent iterations it will already be 31.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `counter` is initialized to zero, incremented in the inner loop, but never reset.

Assuming the initial guess is not prime, `counter` will be incremented to 31 the first time `while(counter<=30 || res!=0)` loop runs. On the second iteration of the outer loop, `counter` is already 31. The inner loop does no iterations and `res` keeps its value from the previous outer loop iteration.

Put `counter = 0` as the first statement in the outer loop rather than initializing `counter`.